# C# 5.0 - PLINQ (using AsParallel() method)

Tags: c#

In "C# 5.0 in a NutShell" book i came across below program:

```
// Calculate prime numbers using a simple (unoptimized) algorithm.
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range (3, 100000-3);
var parallelQuery = from n in numbers.AsParallel()
                    where Enumerable.Range (2, (int) Math.Sqrt (n)).All (i => n % i > 0)
                    select n;
```

I understand that on calling PLINQ's AsParallel() method, input sequence(numbers) is wrapped in a parallel sequence based on ParallelQuery. This is because AsParallel() is an extension method in System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable. It is mentioned that the AsParallel() method causes LINQ query operators that you call subsequently to bind to an alternate set of extension methods defined in ParallelEnumerable.

My question is, in the above whether the inner Enumerable.Range().All() method, which defines the condition for "where" query operator, also converts internally into ParallelEnumerable.Range().All() on calling AsParallel() method on "numbers" squence. Kindly clarify me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Based on observations on 16 core cpu, `Where` on `numbers` will be executed in parallel while the `Enumerable.Range().All()` will be executed in sequence.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared my doubt.